# Remove duplicates ignoring the decimals

Tags: r, duplicates

I have data frame like this,

```
a tr78.3
a tr78.2
a tr79.1
b tr12.2
b tr12.3
```

I would like to delete duplicates in second column ignoring the decimals, so that this is my output (I am ok to take the 1st one),

```
a tr78.3
a tr79.1
b tr12.2
```

There are many way how to take unique values (i.e. df %>% distinct(df$V1, df$V2), but how can I specify my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can extract the substring with `sub`, apply `duplicated` to get a logical index and subset the dataset

```
df1[!duplicated(sub("\\.\\d+$", "", df1[,2])),]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    distinct(V2 = str_replace(V2, "\\.\\d+$", ""), .keep_all = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), V2 = c("tr78.3", 
 "tr78.2", "tr79.1", "tr12.2", "tr12.3")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thank you, akrun! I can't believe this was so easy, I was trying to split, then take unique and so on.. do some complicated things, thanks again